# android: cannot resolve the symbol "urls"

Tags: android, androidhttpclient, android-json

I am new to android to programming and i am following the code from the youtube video but i am getting error "cannot resolve the symbol "urls"" for " HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);".I found out through research that the HttpGet is not supported any more in android is there any way around it

```
    @Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {

        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse respone = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        int status = respone.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (status == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = respone.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("forecast");

            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                Forecast forecast = new Forecast();

                forecast.setCode(object.getString("code"));
                forecast.setDate(object.getString("date"));
                forecast.setDay(object.getString("day"));
                forecast.setHigh(object.getString("high"));
                forecast.setLow(object.getString("low"));
                forecast.setText(object.getString("text"));

                forecastList.add(forecast);


            }
            return true;
        }


    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return false;
}
```

Comment: where you define urls ? just replace urls to params

Comment: thanks....that is so dumb of me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace **urls to params** in your code if you don't define urls in previously in your code.

Answer (score 1):

you have to change the parameter name of your doInBackground method to urls. you are receiving it as params, thats why it tells urls not defined.

```
 @Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {

}
```